# how to trigger blur on input applying angular typehead?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead, angular-bootstrap

I have using the angular bootstrap typehead for small autocomplete and i need to trigger the blur of input on which i have applied the typehead onSelect of typehead.

HTML code:

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="customItemSelected" typeahead-template-url="customAutoCompleteTemplate.html"
 type="text" typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item)" />
```

JS Code

```
$scope.onSelect = function(stateItem){
$scope.customItemSelected = "";
// trigger the blur of input so that placeholder appear
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**html**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="sales" name="example-input-normal" 
                                                        typeahead="value.CompanyName for value in Debtors | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" typeahead-focus/>
```

**js**

```
app.directive('typeaheadFocus', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

      //trigger the popup on 'click' because 'focus'
      //is also triggered after the item selection
      element.bind('click', function () {

        var viewValue = ngModel.$viewValue;

        //restore to null value so that the typeahead can detect a change
        if (ngModel.$viewValue == ' ') {
          ngModel.$setViewValue(null);
        }

        //force trigger the popup
        ngModel.$setViewValue(' ');

        //set the actual value in case there was already a value in the input
        ngModel.$setViewValue(viewValue || ' ');
      });

      //compare function that treats the empty space as a match
      scope.emptyOrMatch = function (actual, expected) {
        if (expected == ' ') {
          return true;
        }
        return actual.indexOf(expected) > -1;
      };
    }
  };
});
```